# SSIS - how to pass good record from file in SSIS instead of failing the package due to bad record

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

I am trying to import a csv file having multiple record, but whenever a bad record occur it is failing the whole package and whole file, how can i prevent that?

Looking for solution: if a file is having 10 record and out which 2 records are bad then 8 correct records should load into destination table and 2 bad records should be loaded in different csv file.

please help

Comment: Check your data flow task there is option to move bad records to different destination.  Also there is option click on the data flow task for fail project on fail of task.

Comment: Where is it failing? Is it the source component (flat file source), a transformation within the package, or saving to a destination. Also note that you can have a bad data situation that is going to blow everything up e.g. row 2 is short a delimiter so the source is going to read row2-col1, row2-col2, row3-col1 as col1, col2, col3 data. It's only on the final row that the delimiter mismatch will be detected (or if the data type of a misread column violates the constraints, it will fail early)

Answer (score 0):

If the issues are preventing the SSIS package from parsing the file, you're looking for this section (double click the source task):

[image: SSIS Error Output options]

This is an Excel source, but this option exists for Flat File if that's what you're using. Expand the "Excel Source Output" section in the middle of the window, then you can select whichever columns are failing (or all columns) in the Column column. Change the dropdown to Redirect Row and click apply.

You then have this red arrow:

[image: SSIS Error Output arrow]

You can drag that to a Destination or other task to output the failed rows.

This works for pretty much aany type of task, not just Source Tasks, though the option might be within a "Configure Error Output" button at the bottom of the window.